# Fatal error LNK1104 with Visual Studio 2017 and CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, dllexport

I have the following header in a file matrix_utils.hpp :

```
#include "someIncludes"

void ReadMtxMatrixHeader(){}

int ScanCurrentLine() {}

void ReadMtxMatrixHeader( {}

template<typename T> void RTS_EXPORTS ReadMtxMatrixToCSR() {}

template<typename T> void RTS_EXPORTS ReadMtxMatrixToColMajorArray() {}
```

The implementation here is not important so I left empty brackets.

The RTS_EXPORTS is a macro for :

```
#  define RTS_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport) // if WIN32
#  define RTS_EXPORTS __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) // if GNUC >=4
```

This header is part of a module called "utils" and is used by a target "rts_test_utils". This code works perfectly fine on Linux and on Windows using Cygwin and CLion. But as soon as I try to use Visual Studio 2017 (my project is a CMake project), I get this error when building "rts_test_utils" :

```
$buildPath\build\x86-Debug\modules\utils\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: 
cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\rts_utilsd.lib'
```

Visual Studio generates the DLL for rts_utils, but not the lib. **If I add a dummy class like the one below to "matrix_utils.hpp", then it works and it creates a rts_utilsd.lib. Why ?**

```
class RTS_EXPORTS Foo{};
```

Comment: My guess is that the compiler doesn't see anything to export, since the functions you want to export are template functions which are never called and therefore optimized away. I think that a rts_utilsd.lib will be created as well if you have `void RTS_EXPORTS foo() { ...}` or if you specialize one of your template functions.

Comment: So it would mean that GNU compiler is smarter because it sees that one of the exported function is used in my test unit "rts_test_utils" even if it is not specialized in the header, so it exports the functions. But MSVC optimizes them away before checking that they are used in my test unit.

Comment: I don't think that this is a question of smart or not; you must not forget that in GNU libraries functions are visible by default and in MSVC libraries they are hidden by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comment from oLen, I added the following code in my matrix_utils.cpp (could have been in the header too) to force compiler to see that a template function is exported:

```
template void RTS_EXPORTS
ReadMtxMatrixToColMajorArray(std::vector<float> &col_major_host_ptr,
                           const std::string filename, bool is_one_based);
```

I know I will use this function with float specialization, so it's not even wasted.